# CGAffineTransform(translationX: , y: ) will only move UIImage View to the right

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

I have two UIButtons for moving UImages left and right accordingly. The code for the both UIButtons is as follows,

```
 @IBAction func MoveLeft(_ sender: Any) {
     let yPosition1 = myslider.frame.origin.y
     let yPosition2 = ImageView.frame.origin.y 
     let yPosition3 = ImageView2.frame.origin.y 

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
     self.myslider.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -0.1, y: yPosition1)
     self.ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -0.1, y: yPosition2)
     self.ImageView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -0.1, y: yPosition3)
 }, completion: nil) 
    } 

 @IBAction func MoveRight(_ sender: Any) {
     let yPosition1 = myslider.frame.origin.y
     let yPosition2 = ImageView.frame.origin.y 
     let yPosition3 = ImageView2.frame.origin.y 

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
     self.myslider.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.1, y: yPosition1)
     self.ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.1, y: yPosition2)
     self.ImageView2.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.1, y: yPosition3)
 }, completion: nil) 
    }
```

the values for the translation are opposite of each other so in theory the buttons should move the UIImages in different directions correct? Although when I run the and try using the "MoveLeft" UIButton the UIImages move in the same direction as if I was using the "MoveRight" UIButton. Any ideas on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you also translating it in the y direction? Shouldn't all the y's be 0? Also, are you sure you have connected the `IBAction`s correctly? Did you perhaps connected both of the buttons to `MoveRight`?

Comment: @Sweeper I thought the same initially but when I had the Y-value translation set to 0 it would move the elements along the Y-axis. Having the Y-value set to "myslider.frame.origin.y" resolved the issue